# .after() function doesn't make stopwatch wait

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I want to create a stowatch in python. I have tried to use time.sleep to make program wait one second so it will work properly, but it didnt work and the button (because its a GUI application made in tkinter) was all the time working. So I used `.after` function but the application doesn't work now too, and when I try to close program it doesn't answer.

I have tried to do my best to repair this but I'm new to python and I can't find the problem.

```
def stop_app():
    global stop
    stop = 1


def start():
    global series, minutes,seconds

    minutes=25,
    seconds=60
    print(minutes, seconds)
    while True :
        if series==4:
            break
        seconds -=1
        print (seconds, minutes)

        if minutes == 00 and seconds ==00:
            #dzwięk
            minutes = 4
            seconds=59
            series +=1

        if seconds ==00:
            minutes-=1
            seconds = 60
            print (seconds, minutes, seria)

        clock = tk.Label(root, height=1, background="#000000", foreground='white',
                         font=("Lemon Milk", 70), anchor=CENTER, text="00:00:00")
        clock.place(x=120, y=90)
        clock.after(1000,start)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand several things your code is doing  or tying to do, but below is something based on it that shows the essential of how to do a timer in tkinter using the universal widget `after()` *method*.

Generally speaking it *replaces* explicit loops like the `while True:` you're using. What it does instead is schedule another call to the same function after the specified delay. Stopping the "loop" is easy, just don't call the `after()` again before returning.

The other important thing to note is that the `Label` for displaying the time is only created *once* and the updated each time `start()` executes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *


def start():
    global hours, minutes, seconds

    if hours == 4:
        return  # Stop timer.

    seconds -= 1

    if seconds == 00:
        minutes -= 1
        seconds = 60

    if minutes == 00 and seconds == 00:
        hours += 1

    clock.config(text=f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}')

    root.after(1000, start)  # Call again in 1 second (1000 ms).


root = tk.Tk()
clock = tk.Label(root, height=1, background="#000000", foreground='white',
                 font=("Lemon Milk", 20), anchor=CENTER, text="00:00:00")
clock.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
hours, minutes, seconds = 0, 25, 60  # Initialize global variables.
start()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Kyle2115: Does this answer your basic question?

Comment: Sorry you waited so long for my answer, but I had some tough time finishing my app. Yes your code helped me a lot and also sorry if the code did not make any sens to you but I tried to make a pomodoro app so it counts from 25 to 0 (learn time) and from 5 to 0 (rest time) (I though you might wanna know). Thank you sir again.

Comment: I feel bad now, that you putted efforts to rewrite my code and help me and I lefted without any feedback. Sorry sir